# Access to elements of Matrix

Tags: python, class, matrix, setter

Help me to implement access and change of elements of matrix using property without `numpy`. I'm a beginner)

What I tried to do

```
class Matrix: 

    def __init__(self, matrix=[[0] * 3 for i in range(3)], n = 0, m = 0, element = 0): 

        self.matrix = matrix 

        self.n = len(matrix) 

        self.m = len(matrix[0]) 

        self.element = element
@property 

def element(self, i, j): 

  return self.__matrix[i][j] 

@element.setter 

def element(self, i, j, new_value): 

  print("{}".format(new_value)) 

  self.__matrix[i][j] = new_value

matrix2 = Matrix([[1,5],[3,3]]) 

print(matrix2.element(1,1).matrix)

matrix2.element(2, 1) = 3 

print(matrix2.element)
```

As a result, there was an error

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: matrix2 = Matrix([[1,5],[3,3]]) 

print(matrix2.element(1,1).matrix) 
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: matrix2.element(2, 1) = 3 

print(matrix2.element) SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Answer (score 0):

First lets do this in a simple way, using methods:

```
class Matrix:

  def __init__(self, matrix=[[0] * 3 for i in range(3)], n = 0, m = 0): 
      self.matrix = matrix 
      self.n = len(matrix) 
      self.m = len(matrix[0]) 

  def getitem(self, i, j):
      return self.matrix[i][j]
  
  def setitem(self, i, j, value):
    self.matrix[i][j] = value
    



matrix2 = Matrix([[1,5],[3,3]])

print(matrix2.getitem(1,1))

matrix2.setitem(1, 1, 5)
```

To use `getitem`, we need to pass indices. To use `setitem`, we need to pass both indices and the new value.

Python provides the same methods with built-in indexing capabilities `__getitem__`, and `__setitem__`. By using `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` instead of `getitem()` and `setitem()`, we can take advantage of Python's built-in indexing capabilities to access and modify elements of our Matrix object.

Thus:

```
class Matrix:

  def __init__(self, matrix=[[0] * 3 for i in range(3)], n = 0, m = 0): 
      self.matrix = matrix 
      self.n = len(matrix) 
      self.m = len(matrix[0]) 

  def __getitem__(self, index):
      i, j = index
      return self.matrix[i][j]
  
  def __setitem__(self, index, value):
    i, j = index
    self.matrix[i][j] = value


  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.matrix)



matrix2 = Matrix([[1,5],[3,3]])

print(matrix2[1, 1])

matrix2[1, 1] =5

print(matrix2)
```